# About Cauchy identity for Schur polynomials

Tags: symmetric-functions, schur-functions, cauchy-identity

(This was originally posted here, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4687466/cauchy-identity-for-schur-functions, and I am reposting it here as it seems to be more appropriate.)

PRELIMINARY.
The Cauchy identity for Schur polynomials reads
$$
\sum_{\lambda}s_\lambda(x_1,...,x_n)s_\lambda(y_1,...,y_n) =\prod_{i,j=1}^n\frac 1{1-x_iy_j},
$$
where $s_\lambda$ are the Schur polynomials and the sum on the left-hand side runs over all partitions (of length $\leq n$).

Denoting $p_k(x_1,...,x_n)=x_1^k+...+ x_n ^k$, we also have the identity
$$
\exp\left(\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{p_k(x_1,...,x_n)}{k}y^k\right) = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac 1{1-x_iy},
$$
which implies that we can rewrite Cauchy identity as
$$
\sum_{\lambda}s_\lambda(x_1,...,x_n)s_\lambda(y_1,...,y_n) =\exp\left(\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{p_k(x_1,...,x_n)p_k(y_1,...,y_n)}{k}\right).\qquad (\star)
$$

THE QUESTION.
Let now $p_1,p_2,...$ be an infinite set of independent variables, and let $S_\lambda(p_1,p_2...)$ be the Schur functions, namely the expression of Schur polynomials in the power-sum polynomials.
Can the identity
$$
\sum_{\lambda}S_\lambda(p_1,p_2,...)s_\lambda(y_1,...,y_n) =\exp\left(\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{p_k}{k}(y_1^k+...+y_n^k)\right)\qquad (\star\star)
$$
be deduced directly from $(\star)$ by an $n\to\infty$ limit argument?

I guess I am missing something (trivial!) about rigorously inferring identities in the ring of symmetric functions (which is the inverse limit as $n\to\infty$ of the rings of symmetric polynomials in $n$ variables) from identities in the rings of symmetric polynomials in $n$ variables.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Here is one possible approach to make the aruement rigorous:

Define the two series on the left and the right as Taylor series over the monomials
$$
y_1^{e_1}
\cdot ... 
\cdot 
y_n^{e_n};
$$
in particular, let
$$[y_1^{e_1}
\cdot ... 
\cdot 
y_n^{e_n}]f(y_1,...,y_n)
$$
denote the coefficient of
$
y_1^{e_1}
\cdot ... 
\cdot 
y_n^{e_n}
$
in $f(y_1,...,y_n)$.
It is important to note that the coefficients are in $\mathbb{C}[[x_1,x_2,...]]$, so that we have that the entire domain of discussion is contained within
$$
(\mathbb{C}[[x_1,x_2,...]])[[y_1,...,y_n]].
$$

Also let
$$
p_{k,n} := p_k(x_1,,...,x_n)
$$
so that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} p_{k,n} = p_k.
$$

Now you have that the identity $(\star)$ is equivalent to
$$
\sum_{\lambda}s_{\lambda,n}(p_1,...,p_n)s_\lambda(y_1,...,y_n) =\exp\left(\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{p_{k,n}p_k(y_1,...,y_n)}{k}\right),\qquad (\star\star\star)
$$
where $s_{\lambda,n}(p_1,...,p_n)$ is defined anlogously to $p_{k,n}$.

Now define a norm, $||\_||_y$, on $(\mathbb{C}[[x_1,x_2,...]])[[y_1,...,y_n]]$ as
$$
||f||_y : = \max_{e \in \mathbb{N}^n} \left|\left|\frac{[y_1^{e_1}
\cdot ... 
\cdot 
y_n^{e_n}]f}{A(e_1\cdot...\cdot e_n,e_1\cdot...\cdot e_n)}\right|\right|_x,
$$
where we define the norm $||\_||_x$ on $\mathbb{C}[[x_1,x_2,...]]$
as
$$
||g||_x : = \max_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\max_{e \in \mathbb{N}^n} \left|\left|\frac{[x_1^{e_1}
\cdot ... 
\cdot 
x_n^{e_n}]g}{A(e_1\cdot...\cdot e_n,e_1\cdot...\cdot e_n)}\right|\right|_\mathbb{C},
$$
where $A(x,y)$ is the ***Ackermann function*** (see [1] below).

> The main idea is that all of the coeffcients of $s_{\lambda,n}$ and
> $p_{k,n}$ are **recursively compuatable** and the Ackermann function
> therefore grows far faster than any of those coefficients (since the Ackermann function is not **primitive recursively computable**).
> It is easy to prove this: simply open up a combinatorics book (e.g., Volume II Chapter 7 of Stanley's book, see [2] below) and notice that the deifnitions of $s_{\lambda,n}$ and
> $p_{k,n}$ can be written as a computer program using only recursion and for-loops.
> Furthermore, sums, products, compositions, etc ... and all of the standard combinatorial operations on primitive recursive generating functions are themselves primitive recursive generating functions.

Therefore, we have that $(\star\star)$ is in the space of functions that converges under this norm and, furthermore, that the limit of $(\star\star\star)$ as $n \to \infty$ is equal to $(\star\star)$ by a straightforward calculation, since we forced "deeper" coefficients involving $x_n$ to have smaller contribution to the norm. In particular, I mean that that the limit of LHS $(\star\star\star)$ as $n \to \infty$ is equal to LHS $(\star\star)$ and likewise for RHS.

There might be a more "elementary" arguement that doesn't involve the Ackermann function, but it will likely involve more messy details invloving $\ell^p$ norms that I, as a computer scientist, would find less simple than invoking elementary computability theory (the result is from ~100 years ago!).

[1] *Ackermann, W.*, [**Zum Hilbertschen Aufbau der reellen Zahlen.**](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01459088), Math. Ann. 99, 118-133 (1928). [ZBL54.0056.06](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:54.0056.06).

[2] *Stanley, Richard P.*, Enumerative combinatorics. Volume 2., Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics. 62. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press. xii, 585 p. (2001). [ZBL0978.05002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0978.05002).

Comment: Whoa, that's one meta trick. I'd be careful not to overuse it, as I'm not sure if it can be applied several times in succession. But anyway, it is overkill: The OP needs a topology, not a norm :)

Comment: I think you mean to say "it could be overkill". In order to confidently say that a topology suffices, you must provide a proof that uses a topology that is not a norm (or metric) and it must be shorter/simpler than my proof. That is totally possible, but I am not going to spend days pulling out my hair to figure that out. Mathematical beauty leads people astray just as often as it guides people :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Here is the strategy that I typically use to derive symmetric-functions
identities from symmetric-polynomials identities. It might not be the most
general strategy, but it has so far been sufficient for myself.

Let $\mathbf{k}$ be the base ring. Consider the $\mathbf{k}$-algebra
$\mathbf{k}\left[  \left[  x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},\ldots\right]  \right]  $ of
formal power series in infinitely many commuting indeterminates $x_{1}
,x_{2},x_{3},\ldots$. If $\mathfrak{m}$ is a monomial and $f\in\mathbf{k}
\left[  \left[  x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},\ldots\right]  \right]  $ is a power series,
then $\left[  \mathfrak{m}\right]  f$ shall denote the coefficient of
$\mathfrak{m}$ in $f$.

We equip $\mathbf{k}\left[  \left[  x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},\ldots\right]  \right]
$ with a topology, which is the product topology coming from viewing
$\mathbf{k}\left[  \left[  x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},\ldots\right]  \right]  $ as an
infinite direct product of copies of $\mathbf{k}$ (indexed by monomials).
Explicitly, this topology can be easily described in terms of limits of nets
(see [Stijn Vermeeren's *Sequences and nets in
topology*](https://stijnvermeeren.be/download/mathematics/nets.pdf) for an
introduction to nets): A net $\left(  f_{s}\right)  _{s\in S}$ of power series
$f_{s}\in\mathbf{k}\left[  \left[  x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},\ldots\right]  \right]  $
(where $S$ is a directed set) converges to a power series $f\in\mathbf{k}
\left[  \left[  x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},\ldots\right]  \right]  $ if and only if for
each monomial $\mathfrak{m}$, the net $\left(  \left[  \mathfrak{m}\right]
f_{s}\right)  _{s\in S}$ converges to $\left[  \mathfrak{m}\right]  f$ in the
discrete topology on $\mathbf{k}$ (that is, $\left[  \mathfrak{m}\right]
f_{s}=\left[  \mathfrak{m}\right]  f$ for all sufficiently high $s$, where the
specific meaning of "sufficiently high" depends on $\mathfrak{m}$).

This topology turns $\mathbf{k}\left[  \left[  x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}
,\ldots\right]  \right]  $ into a topological $\mathbf{k}$-algebra. It is easy
to see that any $f\in\mathbf{k}\left[  \left[  x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}
,\ldots\right]  \right]  $ satisfies
\begin{equation}
f=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f\left(  x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}
,0,0,0,\ldots\right)
\label{eq.darij1.1}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
(since each monomial $\mathfrak{m}$ uses only finitely many indeterminates,
and thus remains unchanged when we replace all the higher indeterminates by
$0$). If $f$ is a symmetric function, then we conventionally write $f\left(
x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}\right)  $ for $f\left(  x_{1},x_{2},\ldots
,x_{n},0,0,0,\ldots\right)  $, so this equality becomes
\begin{align*}
f=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f\left(  x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}\right)  .
\end{align*}

Infinite sums $\sum_{s\in S}f_{s}$ of summable families $\left(  f_{s}\right)
_{s\in S}$ are easily defined using the above topology. Summability of a
family $\left(  f_{s}\right)  _{s\in S}$ means that the net $\left(
\sum_{s\in T}f_{s}\right)  _{T\subseteq S\text{ finite}}$ converges, or,
equivalently, that for each monomial $\mathfrak{m}$, only finitely many $s\in
T$ satisfy $\left[  \mathfrak{m}\right]  f_{s}\neq0$. In particular, if
$\left(  f_{s}\right)  _{s\in S}$ is a family of homogeneous power series, and
if it contains only finitely many degree-$n$ entries for each given
$n\in\mathbb{N}$, then it is summable. Thus, sums like $\sum_{\lambda
\in\operatorname*{Par}}s_{\lambda}$ and $\sum_{k\geq1}p_{k}$ are well-defined.

Now, it is easy to see that if $\left(  f_{s}\right)  _{s\in S}$ and $\left(
g_{t}\right)  _{t\in T}$ are two summable families of power series satisfying
\begin{align*}
\sum_{s\in S}f_{s}\left(  x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n},0,0,0,\ldots\right)
=\sum_{t\in T}g_{t}\left(  x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n},0,0,0,\ldots\right)
\end{align*}
for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then
\begin{equation}
\sum_{s\in S}f_{s}=\sum_{t\in T}g_{t}.
\label{eq.darij1.2}
\tag{2}
\end{equation}
Indeed, this follows by comparing the coefficient of each monomial
$\mathfrak{m}$ (noticing that $\mathfrak{m}$, once again, contains only the
indeterminates $x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$). Note
that I am not sure whether limits commute with summable sums in general, but
fortunately this is not needed to prove \eqref{eq.darij1.2}.

This almost suffices to derive your equality ($\star\star$) from your ($\star
$) (upon taking $\mathbf{k}=\mathbb{Q}\left[  p_{1},p_{2},p_{3},\ldots\right]
$), except that we need one more ingredient: The exponential. The definition
of the exponential is well-known: If $\mathbf{k}$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra,
and if $f\in\mathbf{k}\left[  \left[  x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},\ldots\right]
\right]  $ is a power series with constant term $0$, then the exponential
$\exp f$ of $f$ is defined by
\begin{align*}
\exp f=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\dfrac{f^{k}}{k!},
\end{align*}
which is easily seen to be a sum of a summable family. Thus, we obtain a map
$\exp$
\begin{align*}
& \text{from }\left\{  \text{power series }f\in\mathbf{k}\left[  \left[
x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},\ldots\right]  \right]  \text{ with constant term
}0\right\}  \\
& \text{to }\left\{  \text{power series }f\in\mathbf{k}\left[  \left[
x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},\ldots\right]  \right]  \text{ with constant term
}1\right\}  .
\end{align*}
This map $\exp$ is furthermore continuous (because for each monomial
$\mathfrak{m}$, we can compute $\left[  \mathfrak{m}\right]  \left(  \exp
f\right)  $ from knowing only the finitely many coefficients $\left[
\mathfrak{n}\right]  f$ for the finitely many monomials $\mathfrak{n}$ that
divide $\mathfrak{m}$). As a consequence, it commutes with taking limits and
with taking sums of summable families. The substitution homomorphism
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{k}\left[  \left[
x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},\ldots\right]  \right] &\to \mathbf{k}\left[  \left[
x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}\right]  \right] , \\
f &\mapsto f\left(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n,0,0,0,\ldots\right)
\end{align*}
is also continuous for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and commutes with $\exp$.
The rest is substitution.